# Проверка наличия элементов массива в тексте на python

Tags: python, массивы

Подскажите как на питоне проверить что текст не содержит ни одного из элементов заданного массива?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать метод `find()` для нахождения подстроки в строке:

```
def check(strCheck):
    arr = ['123', 'ban', 'test']
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        if strCheck.find(arr[i]) != -1:
            return False
    return True

print(check('gt23'))
print(check('test42'))
```

Вывод:

```
True
False
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!